# Why Kubernetes REST API is imperative?

Tags: rest, kubernetes, operator-sdk

**EDIT**: As mentioned in [Jonas'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213269/jonas) response Kubernetes REST API can be actually considered as declarative and not imperative.

Kubernetes is well known for its declarative model.
Controller are watching objects in ETCD which contains the desired state (declarative). It compares it to the current state and generates imperative commands to the [imperative Kubernetes API](https://v1-18.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/).

**Which reasons leads Kubernetes project to not expose a declarative HTTP API?**

Thus let the controller/operator do the reconciliation.

An example of declarative REST API, I found is [F5 AS3](https://clouddocs.f5.com/products/extensions/f5-appsvcs-extension/latest/userguide/about-as3.html). And I guess their [Kubernetes operator](https://clouddocs.f5.com/containers/latest/userguide/kubernetes/) built on top of this declarative API is quite straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kubernetes API can be used both *declaratively* and also *imperatively*. For quick development an imperative workflow might work better whereas for traceability and production workload a declarative workflow is recommended.

### Declarative HTTP example using curl

This requires to run `kubectl proxy` first.

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/yaml' --data '
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-example
spec:
  replicas: 3
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
' http://127.0.0.1:8001/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments
```

The Kubernetes API is **declarative** in the sense that you always specify **what** you want, e.g. `replicas: 2` instead of e.g. `create 2 replicas` that would be the case in an *imperative* API. The controllers then "drives" the state to "what" you specified in a reconciliation loop.

See:

- [Declarative Management of Kubernetes Objects Using Configuration Files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/)
- [Imperative Management of Kubernetes Objects Using Configuration Files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/imperative-config/)
- [Managing Kubernetes Objects Using Imperative Commands](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/imperative-command/)

From your link:

> The Application Services 3 Extension uses a declarative model, meaning you send a declaration file using a single Rest API call.

the Kubernetes API works exactly the same when you apply yaml-manifest files using e.g. `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`

Comment: I understand **Kubectl** tool allows bothdeclarative and imperative approach, But why the **HTTP** API (called by the Kubectl or controllers) is imperative. Could have it been declarative? what is the rationale behind? I am missing something

Comment: kubectl is just a http-client. The HTTP API is declarative.

Comment: Actually I was surprised to see it is imperative.

Comment: Not sure if I do twice this query `$ curl -H 'content-type: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/testapi/pods  -d '{"kind":"Pod","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"name":"nginx-via-api","labels":{"run":"nginx"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"nginx","image":"nginx"}],"restartPolicy":"Never"}}' | jq .code
=> 409`. I got a 409. If the API were declarative it would not return a 409, and update the object if there was a change on some field, or do nothing if same object (idempotency)? wdyt

Comment: to update, you need to use `PUT` and you can run it many times, it is idempotent. You can only create a resource with a unique name once, it is not a failure to do it twice but you get a message about it.

Comment: also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Idempotent

Comment: Very clear, understand your point on why  Kubernetes API is declarative!